# Does bacteria and virus have souls in them?

Tags: vedas, gods

Even bacteria and virus have souls in them.? According to vedas how many living species are in to this world?

Comment: 8,40,000 species if I remember!

Comment: Viruses are at the border of living and non-living. May be they have half a soul.

Comment: @LazyLubber What is half a soul?:D

Comment: Yes, prAna, chetanA and AtmA are used interchangeably.So soul is present in every being.

Comment: Killing bacteria a sin?

Comment: Whatever can harm your life can be killed by a householder.The rule for the monks is different@Karmaisrealman

Comment: @commonman Do monks take antibiotics?

Comment: @LazyLubber They in these days do take, but when the rules were framed there was no antibiotic :)

Comment: you have asked 2 separate questions. please limit questions to one question per posting. btw, this is a duplicate question. already answered. short answer, yes they do, as do all the individual cells in your body.

Comment: @AkshayS looks like you missed one zero, the number of species are 84 lacks.

Comment: That’s insane I can’t imagine the complexity of gods creation. I should be very thankful to him.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal Perhaps I dont remember exact lack. Either 8, 40 or 84 I forgot. Ok fine will remember now!